# Burn the [homework2] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, tags

After having lost out on the [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) for their homework questions, students have found another tag for themselves. The [homework2](/questions/tagged/homework2) tag. Currently, there are no questions tagged to it(luckily), so can we just go ahead and burninate it? I really doubt if we require such a tag.

Comment: Don't worry, it should be removed in the next 24 hours.

Comment: But that's if there are no more questions tagged right?! What if by then, some other questions are tagged with it?

Comment: Screw it, set fire to `.*homework.*` tags everywhere.

Comment: @Makoto - Is that really possible?! I mean the devs here can do anything, but doing such a thing will be great.

Comment: I don't know.  Although if we start seeing questions tagged with some variant of `homework` therein, they may build regex support in their blacklist capabilities yet.

Comment: Wow... homework2? Really?

Comment: @AndrewBarber - Sadly, but yes. Somehow, they keep finding some ways to get the *homework* thing into the system. :(

Comment: There aren't any tags containing homework in them apart from that one.

Comment: next thing we know there will be a `working-at-home` tag or a `schoolwork` tags

Comment: Homework 2.0 is obviously a newer, more advanced version of Homework. School must be getting *really* hard.

Comment: I have removed this tag from two questions today already.

Comment: coming soon: [tag:homeworklol]

Comment: [*Homework? Damn to the depths whatever muttonhead thought up 'homework!'*](http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Parley)

Comment: The question is - who created this tag and should we revoke a few privileges of said user?

Comment: @Dukeling: What baffles me is that it must've been a user with at least *1500 rep*.  Perhaps the 1-rep users have a leader?

Comment: Wait for h0m3w0rk tag...